# undefined method `refer=' on :set_attribute - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise and have a database column in my Member model for refer which I want to set before creation when a new member registers. The `refer:string` needs to store a unique random string that can later be used as a referral code.

The error that I get is: `undefined method 'refer=' for #<Member:0x971ece0>`

Member model:

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
 before_create :set_refer

private
 def set_refer
   self.refer = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)
 end
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "members", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
 t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
 t.string   "reset_password_token"
 t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
 t.datetime "remember_created_at"
 t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
 t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
 t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
 t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
 t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
 t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
 t.boolean  "admin"
 t.string   "refer"
 t.string   "referral_code"
 t.index ["email"], name: "index_members_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
 t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_members_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
end
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you just add schema of your Member model to the question ?

Comment: Try to create instance of Member in rails console manually.

Comment: Did you restart the server after running migrations?

Comment: @RSB, it was a complete rookie move from my part, I did not restart after the migration, thanks it's sorted.